# Cannot find module 'fs/promises' Electron JS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

Good morning,

I have created a program in Vue JS, this connects with an API that I have created in a main.js file to execute system commands.

The problem I have is that when compiling for production with electron I get the following error:

[image: ERROR]

I use the command npm run electron: build

When I use npm run electron:serve work without problems

Anyone have any idea why is the error and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue .. Update to the newest nodejs-Version will fix this issue.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I experienced this issue a few days ago as well. I realized that trying to fix another issue, I deleted the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, then run the `npm install` command. This made the build to fail with 'fs/promises'. There are 2 solutions to this issue:

1. Download the latest stable Node version. This should have the 'fs/promises' module and will fix the issue.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder and bring back the old `package-lock.json` file to ensure that the package versions remain the same. Then run the `npm install` command and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: Hey there, I did upgrade my NodeJS version and worked for me, I used terminal commands in order to upgrade in a faster way, you can follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js. Take into consideration that maybe other projects you have are incompatible with this new version you are installing, in that case, consider using NVM.

Answer (score 32):

downgrade electron
"electron-builder": "^22.10.5",
or upgrade nodejs to 14+ v

Comment: Downgrading the electron-builder version worked for me, with node 12.18.4. This should be the accepted answer since retrieving old package-lock.json is not going to work when installing everything first time.

Comment: Upgrading to node v14 worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you're not using this dependency directly and this pops up at some building stage, it's very likely it's the Node version. Upgrading to 14 solved.

Comment: Switching from `"^22.10.5"` to `"22.10.5"` worked for me

Answer (score 14):

In that case I fixed the problem in that way:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
```

Instead of:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');
```

Comment: You should not use old syntax in 2023. This is the modern esm style import:
`import { readFile } from 'fs/promises'` or without a specific import: `import { promises as fs } from 'fs'`

Answer (score 12):

downgrade to `"electron-builder": "~22.10.5"` is working for me

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was using `nvm` to manage multiple node versions.

During the npm package installation, and throughout development, I used `Node v14` but for some reason, my terminal was pointing to `Node v12` when I tried bundling my program afterwards.

Switching it back to `Node v14` using `nvm use 14` solved my issue.

So make sure you're using the correct node version.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade to `electron-updater@5.0.0`.  It has patch changes replacing `fs/promises` with `fs-extra` to support legacy versions of electron.

Answer (score 1):

### 2023 / ESM answer

```
npm i @types/node
```

Then in your JS/TS:

```
import { readFile } from "node:fs/promises";
```

or to import the entire library (renaming it, since the name `promises` is a bit vague)

```
import fsPromises from "node:fs/promises";
```

Answer (score 0):

got the same error "Cannot find module 'fs/promises'" while I don't use electron.

so the problem is not only related to electron

solved the problem just by upgrading nodejs from v13.9.0 to v14.19.3

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you (and I'm not using Electron either), and you have to stay on Node 12 like me (because the code you are maintaining is ancient), pray that you can get to one of the npm-shrinkwrap.json files you used that worked, then go through package.json, force every version to what was in the shrinkwrap file, rm -rf node_modules, and npm install.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue a few days ago. I realized that trying to fix another issue, I deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file, then run the

```
npm install
```

This made the build to fail with 'fs/promises'.
Delete the node_modules folder and bring back the old package-lock.json file to ensure that the package versions remain the same
then run the npm command with force

```
npm install --force
```

it work for me..

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, after upgrading the `electron-builder` from `v. 21.4.0` to `23.0.2`, updated with the command:
 
`sudo npm install -g electron-builder@23.0.2`

I solved updating npm, and then node.js.

1. Update `npm`:

   `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`
2. Install `nodejs` from [https://nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/)

Now it works with :

- Electron-builder: 23.0.2 (command `electron-builder --version`)
- Npm: 8.7.0 (command `npm --version`)
- Nodejs: v16.15.0 (command `node --version`)