# Is it possible to compile javascript/c++/html into an exe with the source code not being visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, exe

I'm creating a game in html canvas and I'm seeing if it is possible to compile a set of html/js/c++ to make the source code not visibile. I want to have all features that a modern browser has, such as canvas, svg, custom mouse cursour etc...

I tried electron and nwjs but both had the source code obviously and the game could be edited, hacked, changed easily by going through javascript and html files.

Comment: Checkout electron and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515099/how-to-package-an-electron-app-into-a-single-executable

Comment: try to encryption the HTML (such as ZIP with password). If you need to use it, just decrypt them.